# GORM create criteria - Using 'having' clause of SQL

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

I have a dummy cafeteria project wherein I have three domain classes: `User`, `Product` and `Transaction`.

Here's how the classes are defined:

```
class User {

    String name
    int employeeId
    long balance = 800
    static constraints = {
        balance(max: 800L)
    }   
}

class Product {

    String type 
    int quantityInStock
    float price
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Transaction {

    int quantityBought
    static belongsTo = [user: User, product: Product]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Now I want to **find out the number of/list of users who have bought more than, say 2 products**.
How do I do it using Grails createCriteria?

This is what I tried:

```
Transaction.createCriteria().list(){
    projections {
        groupProperty('user')
        'product' {
            count('id','numberOfPurchases')
        }
    }
    gt('numberOfPurchases',2)
}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Stacktrace:

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: numberOfPurchases of: cafeteria.dummy.Transaction 
at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1618)                    
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:4)                                                                           
at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:37)                                
at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.execute(ConsoleController.groovy:59)                       
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)   
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)                          
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                         
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)                         
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I access this alias `numberOfPurchases` outside the projections block so as to use it in `gt`?

Comment: You could use sub query with HQL.  Some details are at section 7.4 of http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html

Comment: @Mamun, I'm aware it can be done using HQL. I wanted to know if it can be done using criteria.

Comment: you can use DetachedCriteria though it may not be that straight forward as you probably are expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Internally `GORM` uses Hibernate and currently Hibernate doesn't have support for `having clause` in `Criteria` API. The reason you are not able to get `numberOfPurchases` outside projections block is that the restrictions are added to where clause and you can't use an aggregation alias in `where` clause.
Although JPA has support for having clause.

But if you still want to achieve this using GORM Criteria you can. But you would have to modify your query a little bit and it would not involve use of having clause and will require a subquery.

Modified query will be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT this_.user_id FROM transaction this_ where 2 < (SELECT count(sub_.id) FROM transaction sub_ WHERE sub_.user_id=this_.user_id)
```

And GORM for it would be:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions
import org.hibernate.criterion.Subqueries

DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Transaction, 'sub').with {
    setProjection Projections.count('sub.id')
    add Restrictions.eqProperty('sub.user', 'this.user')
}

List<User> users = Transaction.createCriteria().list() {
    projections {
        distinct("user")
    }
    add Subqueries.lt(2l, subQuery)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative solution, @Sandeep. I actually wanted to clarify if `Criteria` supports the `having clause`.

Comment: @SAKSHISINGHAL No it doesn't